# Android Multiple EditText fields in a ListAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext, listadapter

I have a screen (see picture) that is populated by a GridView using a custom extension of BaseAdapter.

When the user enters some text into the EditText fields, the text they entered is liable to shifting around or disappearing entirely. I'm assuming this has to do with the recycling of views, but my understanding of listadapters is poor.

The fields behave fine initially thanks to the Manifest entry android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", but they shift around if you scroll chaotically.

All I am looking to do is get some String data from the user. The Strings are stored in a global String array "strings[]". The strings array is updated by MyTextWatcher, which is just an extension of TextWatcher.

The code (attempts) to ensure that the TextWatchers always know the position of their EditText field within the grid. That way, the TextWatchers should always be updating strings[] with the correct index.

[image: shows an example of the carnage]

I have every reason to believe that the issue derives from my getView method():

```
public void initList()
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.shape, strings)
    {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null  || convertView.getTag() == null)  {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.shape, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_text);
                holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_image);
                holder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shape_edittext);

                holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {                      
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){}
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (gameType == SHAPES_ABSTRACT && before == 0 && count == 1) {
                            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.editText.getWindowToken(), 0);                               
                        }    
                    }
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        strings[holder.ref]= s.toString(); 
                    }
                });

                convertView.setTag(holder);                    
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.ref = position;
            holder.editText.setText(strings[position]);                             

            holder.image.setBackgroundResource(images[position]);

            if (gameType == SHAPES_ABSTRACT)
                holder.text.setText("Seq:");
            else
                holder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);   

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    grid.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would again preface this, as in the other answer, by saying I wouldn't implement it this way.  You're doing scary stuff.  Carrying lots of references around.  However, I think this should help:

```
Map<EditText, MyTextWatcher> watchers = new HashMap<EditText, MyTextWatcher>();

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View MyView = convertView;
    if (MyView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        MyView = li.inflate(R.layout.shape, null);
    }

    EditText textbox = (EditText) MyView.findViewById(R.id.shape_edittext);

    textbox.setText(strings[position]);
    MyTextWatcher myTextWatcher = watchers.get(textbox);

    if(myTextWatcher == null)
    {
        myTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher(position, textbox);
        watchers.put(textbox, myTextWatcher);
    }

    myTextWatcher.setIndex(position);

    ImageView image = (ImageView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.shape_image);
    image.setBackgroundResource(images[position]);

    TextView text = (TextView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.shape_text);
    text.setText("Seq:");

    return MyView;
}
```

The problem here is that you created the TextWatcher, added it to an EditText, but then kept a reference to it in a list by position, so the references between EditText and the TextWatcher were broken.

This solution assumes that 'equals' for EditText will do an object instance compare and not a value compare.  If that is NOT the case, you'd need to keep a reference to all EditText instances, and do an '==' compare to each and find a match.

I think there are safer ways to do this, but give it a shot.

Comment: I am trying a different approach based on a your earlier answer. The code above is updated and is probably a hell of a lot more sensible. I am still having issues with the text in the edittext fields shifting around if I scroll violently. Do you see anything outstanding in the code?

Comment: Looking at my old code, there is a problem.  The 'addTextChangedListener' will just keep adding new listeners, so its easy to imagine eventually you'll have many listeners registered for a single EditText.  To see if a simple version will work, don't recycle the View.  Always inflate a new view.  If that works, and you want to recycle for performance reasons, looking into ways of updating or removing that TextWatcher from the EditText.

Comment: One way to do it.  the images are probably going to be the big memory issue, so instead of having your EditText in the xml, create a FrameLayout to hold the EditText, then in your code, get that FrameLayout, remove all children, create an EditText in code, and add your TextWatcher.  This certainly gets into the "ugly" realm, but it looks like EditText doesn't have a "removeAllTextChangeListeners".  You need to keep a reference to the one you gave it, which is itself kind of ugly, and would need something like the Map in the code above.

Comment: Yep, the addTextChangedListener will keep adding a new listener on top of the old one, and who knows when or when the views will be recycled. I had a similar problem to this and I found that having EditTexts inside ListViews is playing with fire. There's a lot of things that can (and do) go wrong, or just behave strangely.

Comment: Never mind, I SOLVED IT!!!!!!!! And I owe it all to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358342/edittext-in-a-list-arent-working-the-way-they-should .  Thanks for the help along the way.