# Why multiple editext get focus inside listview with base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I spend days to figure out what happen here.

- Simple listview with custom base adapter.
- Listview contains rows.
- Each row contains multiple edittext.

---

### | edittext | row 1

### | edittext | row 2

### | edittext | row 3

### | edittext | row 4

The problem is if i type on edittext in row 1, edittext in row 3 is affected. Its not just duplicate the text, but also isFocus. Same if i type on edittext in row 2, edittext in row 4 is also affected.

I used ViewHolder class. 
I check the converView if it empty, then initialize the edittext to ViewHolder, then save it to converView's tag.
If the converView is not empty, then reuse converView and get the ViewHolder from converView's tag.

Please help.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View converView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ViewHolder holder;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (converView == null) {
        converView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapteraktivitasakhirpanen, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.tvPemanen);
        holder.atv1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.atvGandeng1);
        holder.atv2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.atvGandeng2);
        holder.atv3 = (AutoCompleteTextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.atvGandeng3);

        if (totalGandeng > 0) {
            holder.atv1.setMinWidth(toDP(200));
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listGandeng1);
            holder.atv1.setAdapter(adapter);
            holder.atv1.setTag(i);
        }

        converView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        System.out.println("converView not null");
        holder = (ViewHolder) converView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tv.setText(names.get(i));
}
```

---

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    AutoCompleteTextView atv1;
    AutoCompleteTextView atv2;
    AutoCompleteTextView atv3;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check my code

Comment: in which android version you are running your application?

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358342/edittext-in-a-list-arent-working-the-way-they-should..

Comment: Cant use that answer. Actually i have 3 edittext as you can see at my ViewHolder and i have another function that refresh these Autocompletetextview, the result is StackOverFlowError.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to solve your problem:

1. Don't use `ListView`'s cache technique. So your code will like this:

   ```
   public View getView(int i, View converView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       ViewHolder holder;
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       converView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapteraktivitasakhirpanen, null);

       holder = new ViewHolder();

       holder.tv = (TextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.tvPemanen);
       holder.atv1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.atvGandeng1);
       holder.atv2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.atvGandeng2);
       holder.atv3 = (AutoCompleteTextView) converView.findViewById(R.id.atvGandeng3);

       if (totalGandeng > 0) {
           holder.atv1.setMinWidth(toDP(200));
           adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listGandeng1);
           holder.atv1.setAdapter(adapter);
           holder.atv1.setTag(i);
       }

       holder.tv.setText(names.get(i));
   }
   ```

**This solution will make your app run slower.**

2. If you want to use this cache technique. You should handle all `AuctoCompleteTextView`'s `TextChangeListener` and everytime text changed you must save it so that you can restore it when `Listview` create the itemview again.

Comment: Hi Cuong, please tell me why i shouldnt use listView's cache?

Comment: After i try your solutions, actually i should use both. Because everytime the view scrolled, my View is recycled and the adapter create new View.

Comment: Cant use your answer. Actually i have 3 edittext as you can see at my ViewHolder and i have another function that refresh these Autocompletetextview, the result is StackOverFlowError.

Comment: @rjrain I think you need a boolean flag to check if AutocompleteTextView's TextChangeListener is called when user edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help. But i found a better way that suit my case.

So what i did is create all the view inside constructor and then return the view on getView() with position.

```
public myAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
   this.context = context;
   this list = list;
   createAllView();
}

public void createAllView() {
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      /**
      * Create layout view using LayoutInflater
      */
      listView.add(view);
   }
}

public View getView(int pos, View converView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
   return listView.get(pos);
}
```